# How to select Input checkbox and create automatically div in other div

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a simple form with two checkbox:

```
<form id="formTest">
    <input type="checkbox" id="imageOne"> <img src="/uploads/imagens/imageone.jpg">
    <input type="checkbox" id="imageTwo"> <img src="/uploads/imagens/imageone.jpg"> 
</form>  

<div id="test">
</div>
```

I'm following this jQuery tutorial for creating new elements: http://jquerybrasil.org/criando-elementos-com-jquery/

```
<script>
    $("#formTest").change(function () {       
       $('<div>',{
         id : 'imageTow or One',
       });

    });    
</script>
```

When any checkbox is selected, I need to create a div inside `div#test` with the corresponding checkbox image inside it. How can I do it?

Below is a image explaining what should happen.

[image]

Comment: I'm having a really hard time trying to understand what you want to do. Is it possible for you to correct the grammar here so the question is more clear?

Comment: Sorry, I added one image in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, whenever a checkbox is clicked it should create a div inside `div test` with the corresponding checkbox image.

I made some changes in the form, so jQuery can get the image elements easier.

- Corrected the inputs, they must have name and value attributes
- Added label elements, the `for` is a reference for the input with that id
- Bonus: because we are using label and it is referencing the checkbox, when you click the image itself, it will also behave as if you clicked the checkbox, this eases the user experience

---

```
<form id="formTest">
    <input type="checkbox" name="imageOne" id="imageOne" value="1"/>
    <label for="imageOne" id="labelimageOne">
        <img src="/uploads/imagens/imageone.jpg">
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="imageTwo" id="imageTwo" value="1"/>
    <label for="imageTwo" id="labelimageTwo">
        <img src="/uploads/imagens/imageone.jpg">
    </label>
</form>
```

Your `div test` is lacking the `id` attribute, so correct it:

```
<div id="test">
</div>
```

This is the code you're looking for, I also commented some lines for better understanding.

```
// Whenever a checkbox is clicked, execute the following function
$('form#formTest input:checkbox').on('click', function(){

    // this var will be true when checkbox is marked, false otherwise
    var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');

    // this var contains the id attribute of the checkbox clicked
    var idClicked = $(this).attr('id'); 

    // When checkbox is marked, create the div with image inside
    if (isChecked) {

        // this var contains the div test element
        var divTest = $('div#test'); 

        // this var contains the closest img element to the checkbox clicked
        var image   = $('#label'+idClicked+' img');

        // Append a div inside div test, with the corresponding image html
        divTest.append('<div class="imageOne">'+image.prop('outerHTML')+'</div>');
    }
});
```

PS: `.prop('outerHTML')` will work if you're using jQuery 1.6+

Guessing from the link you pasted, I guess you know portuguese. If you have trouble with this english stackoverflow, you can use [Portuguese Stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Thank you Edson Horacio Junior, But source code appear ***<div class="imageOne">[object Object]</div>** missing correctly display the image. I wrote the English version by the community to be more active